# SQL Group By on field from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I group by in sql on a field from other table. Here's my code

```
select 
  sum(a.trans_amount), (
    select 
      ledger_name 
    from 
      ledger_master 
    where 
      ledger_master.ledger_code = transaction_ledger.ledger_code
  ) as ledger_name,
  ledger_code 
from 
  transaction_ledger 
where 
  ledger_parent = 'Sundry Debtors' 
group by 
  ledger_code,
  ledger_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not join the results and then grouping by?

```
SELECT 
SUM(Trans_Amount), 
A.Ledger_Name, 
A.Ledger_Code 
FROM Transaction_Ledger A INNER JOIN Ledger_Master B 
ON A.Ledger_Code=B.Ledger_Code 
WHERE A.Ledger_Parent='Sundry Debtors' 
GROUP BY A.Ledger_Code, A.Ledger_Name
```

Your Ledger_Master and Transaction_Ledger has a related column "Ledger_Code" which you have used in the example query you have provided.

Keeping that in mind, you can proceed to group by the required fields after a join on those two fields of the two tables.

Luckily, the select list you want (Name & Code) can be used to group as well - thus not violating the grouping rules.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one ledger master record per transaction ledger, this might be what you are after:

```
select 
  sum(t.trans_amount),
  m.ledger_name, 
  t.ledger_code 
from 
  transaction_ledger t
    inner join
  ledger_master m
    on t.ledger_code = m.ledger_code
where 
  t.ledger_parent = 'Sundry Debtors'
group by 
  t.ledger_code,
  m.ledger_name
```